# Showing a new Window right next to a DataCell in DataGrid (WPF)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want a scenario when a user clicks on a cell in DataGrid in WPF, I want to open NumPad next to it (This is basically for touch based input). 
The NumPad, I understand is a separate window.

1) How can I know which Cell is selected
 2) how can I show the NumPad next to the cell? 
3) How can I find the coordinates of cell to position my NumPad?
 4) How can I set the value of cell based on NumPad entry?

NumPad is a WPF User Control in the same application.
DataGrid is a .NET 4 Control.
It's a normal Windows Desktop application

Comment: Some questions: 1) What sort of NumPad are you talking about? Is this a custom control? Or an external application which is started in a separate window? Or something else? 2) Is this a normal Windows application or a mobile application? 3) Do you use the default .NET4 DataGrid or a commercial one (e.g. Infragistics, Xceed...)?

Answer (score 8):

This is not a trivial task and you should have some knowledge of WPF to accomplish this, but here are some ideas what you might look for:

1. The [`DataGridCell.IsSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isselected.aspx) property tells you whether a cell is selected.
2. I would use a [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx) to show the NumPad directly besides the cell.
3. If you use a `Popup` you do not need the coordinates, but you can specify the relative placement using the [`Popup.Placement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placement.aspx) property. Also see this MSDN document: [Popup Placement Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596.aspx)
4. You could try to use a Binding from the NumPad to the user control in the DataGridCell.

Using the [`DataGrid.CellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.cellstyle.aspx) or the [`DataGridColumn.CellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle.aspx) property you can specify an alternate style for all cells of the DataGrid or some specific column. Within this style, you could change the template and add a `Popup` which is opened only if the current cell is selected. You can easily achieve this by binding the [`Popup.IsOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen.aspx) property to the [`DataGridCell.IsSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcell.isselected.aspx) property.

This is just an initial idea. You will still have to have a look at the provided MSDN links and also read some other stuff about WPF. Although it might take some time to learn this 'WPF way' (i.e. only XAML), it is (in my eyes) much easier than using lots of code-behind to determine the currently selected cell, positioning a control at the correct location, transferring the data from the NumPad to the cell and so on...

Comment: Thanks gehho. I am ok with using Code-behind. In the other question you mentioned using TransformtoAncestor to find the coordinates of the DataCell and then position the new Window next to it. Though I get some weird coordinates. Not sure what's going on. The thing I don't understand is why is this so difficult in WPF and was a piece of cake in Winforms (and heck even HTML/CSS).

Comment: Maybe you should post your code... Otherwise I think I cannot help to find the problem.

Comment: @nEEbz what are you missing from this answer? it is not exactly what you asked for, but it is the solution to your problem and this is the wpf way (i'd also recommend doing it like that). also: it is not _so difficult_. if you have a specific question to this answer - ask further! If you are new to wpf read more and try to get this solution working. btw: many people coming from winforms are ok with code behind. many mvvm enthusiasts are not.

Comment: @Markus: does this means that I need to put my Numpad form inside a Popup ? And how can I place a Popup relative to a DataGridCell ?

Comment: Have a look at step 3). You will need to change the CellStyle and give it a custom template. This template should include a Popup control with your NumPad.

Answer (score 3):

I really like Gehho's answer. 
Doing as he suggested, besides using the Template column over styling text columns, resulted in the following XAML:

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="R" Binding="{Binding Color.R}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="G" Binding="{Binding Color.G}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding Color.B}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alpha" Binding="{Binding Color.A}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thumb">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="border" Background="{Binding}">
                                <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=border, Mode=OneWay}"
                                         PopupAnimation="Fade"
                                         Placement="MousePoint">
                                    <Border Width="200" Height="200" Background="{Binding Background , ElementName=border, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </Popup>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="SteelBlue"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Lime"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Cyan"/>             
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope this helps!