# Setting position of child window within main window (parent)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, wpf-controls

I have a custom messagebox done in wpf.

**Custom messagebox view xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="My.XAML.Controls.Windows.WpfMessageBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WpfMessageBox"  MinHeight="160" 
        MinWidth="420" MaxHeight="750" MaxWidth="750" 
        Background="Transparent" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True">

</Window>
```

From my main window (parent) I show this custom wpf messagebox window when user clicks on a button, as an example of the call from the button when it is clicked:

```
var messageBoxResult = WpfMessageBox.Show("Title", "MyMessage",
    MessageBoxButton.YesNo, WpfMessageBox.MessageBoxImage.Warning, this, EnumLocation.TopLeft);
```

*Custom messagebox code-behind xaml.cs:

```
public partial class WpfMessageBox : Window
{
    private WpfMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string caption, string text, MessageBoxButton button, MessageBoxImage image, Window parent, EnumLocation location)
    {
        switch (location)
        {
            case MessageBoxLocation.TopLeft:
                this.Top = parent.Top; // works
                this.Left = parent.Left; // works
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.TopCenter:
                this.Top = parent.Top;
                this.Left = ? // what goes here?                    
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.TopRight:
                this.Top = parent.Top;
                this.Left = (parent.Left + parent.Width) - this.Width; // not working, what goes here?
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.MiddleLeft:
                this.Left = parent.Left;
                this.Top = ? // what goes here? 
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.MiddleCenter:
                this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen; // not working so what goes here?
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.MiddleRight:
                this.Top = ? // what goes here? 
                this.Left = ? // what goes here? 
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.BottomLeft:
                this.Top = (parent.Top + parent.Height) - this.Height; // Not working this
                this.Left = parent.Left;
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.BottomCenter:
                this.Top = (parent.Top + parent.Height) - this.Height;    // not working
                this.Left = ? // what goes here?                
                break;
            case MessageBoxLocation.BottomRight:
                this.Top = (parent.Top + parent.Height) - this.Height; // not working
                this.Left = (parent.Left + parent.Width) - this.Width; // not working
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In some case I have no idea to set it, and others I set but it does not work.
Could someone help me to set them correctly?

Comment: I think the problem is that width, height for child window cannot be known after load event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446602/wpf-set-dialog-window-position-relative-to-main-window I will have a look and come back with a feedback.

Comment: Of course you cannot access this.Width in a static method. What is the Show method supposed to do with your window...?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
switch (location)
    {
        case MessageBoxLocation.TopLeft:
            this.Top = parent.Top; // works
            this.Left = parent.Left; // works
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.TopCenter:
            this.Top = parent.Top;
            this.Left = (parent.Width + this.Width) /2; // what goes here?                    
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.TopRight:
            this.Top = parent.Top;
            this.Left = parent.Width - this.Width;
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.MiddleLeft:
            this.Left = parent.Left;
            this.Top = (parent.Height - this.Height) /2;
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.MiddleCenter:
            this.Left = (parent.Width - this.Width) /2 ;
            this.Top = (parent.Height - this.Height) /2;
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.MiddleRight:
            this.Top = (parent.Height - this.Height) /2;
            this.Left = parent.Width - this.Width;
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.BottomLeft:
            this.Top = parent.Height - this.Height;
            this.Left = parent.Left;
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.BottomCenter:
            this.Top = parent.Height - this.Height;   
            this.Left = (parent.Width - this.Width) /2 ;
            break;
        case MessageBoxLocation.BottomRight:
            this.Top = parent.Height - this.Height; 
            this.Left = parent.Width - this.Width;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, you forgot some things: in some cases you must add "parent.Top +" followed by what you indicated. In other cases also you forgot "parent.Left +" . This is necessary before you assign result to this.Top and this.Left. If not, it will not work. Also you have a mistake in case MessageBoxLocation.TopCenter, for case this.Left is parent.Width - this.Width not parent.Width + this.Width. So please correct these things in your post.

Comment: Also I must say that it is working perfectly in all cases when parent window (in which custom messagebox windows is contained) has a custom size (not maximized). If parent window is maximized, it is not working, in this case, when messagebox window is open it is always shown in the last location. Any idea what it is happening when parent window is maximized? I have seen that when parent window is maximized, Top and Left coordinates are not being updated so when passing parent window to messagebox, it is failling when locating itself on the screen. I will open another thread for this

Comment: Also I have seen you use Width and Height but I use ActualWidth and ActualHeight respectively. The result is the same, no difference so I would like to know what is the difference. Do you  know? Correct the things I have said you in the first comment and I will accept your answer.